# Cordova : Content Security Policy directive: "media-src *"

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

Here is my meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src http://* 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I am using this meta tag to call server's socket.io.js file on port like :

```
<script src="https://example.co:3344/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This is for WebRTC (rtcmulticonnection), so my stream event triggered and stream create a media :

```
rtcMultiConnection.onstream = function(event) {
    if (event.stream.getVideoTracks().length) {
        $('.users-container').append(event.mediaElement);
    }
}
```

And error occures :

> Refused to load media from 'blob:http://localhost:8000/74677955-8811-43d0-bf30-2362208364d7' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src *".

It works in Mozilla Firefox, but not work in Android, Chrome Browser and IOS.

**EDIT**

AndroidManifest permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I could not see android error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try 'media-src blob:' in your meta tag as well as the wildcard:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src http://* 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src * blob:">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/media-src