# angular2-qrscanner Refused to load media from 'blob:https://<azureWebApp>/'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, azure-web-app-service, qr-code, npm-start

Please help. Not able to host angular2-scanner over azure WebApp. While running over localhost:4200 the component works like a charm. But after hosting all browsers start to give the following errors.

> Refused to load media from
>   'blob:https:///5c07044f-447c-45a9-979e-458d5e955f8f'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'unsafe-inline' data: https:". Note that 'media-src' was
>   not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: You could refer this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/46069233/10383250

Comment: @GeorgeChen Application hosted as an Azure WebApp. I added meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://<WebApp>.azurewebsites.net 'unsafe-eval'; style-src http://* 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src * blob:"> to index.html. Still not working.